# Saving ssh key fails

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

i just started a Git tutorial and I get to a deadend: I try to generate a rsa key part and it fails.
I did this, in git bash:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myemail.com"
```

And i got this:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Eva/.ssh/id_rsa):
enter passphrase:
enter same passphrase again:
open /c/Users/Eva/.ssh/id_rsa failed: no such file or directory.
Saving the key failed:/c/Users/Eva/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

I tried to save in a different folder and it went OK. but now i do the command `ssh -T git@github.com`  and it gives me the error `permisson denied (publickey).`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you prefer to use a GUI to create the keys

1. Use Putty Gen to generate a key
2. Export the key as an open SSH key
3. As mentioned by @VonC create the .ssh directory and then you can drop the private and public keys in there
4. Or use a GUI program (like [Tortoise Git](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/)) to use the SSH keys

For a walkthrough on putty gen for the above steps, please see http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_create_and_use_public_keys_with_ssh.html

Answer (score 50):

If you're using Windows, the unix-style default path of ssh-keygen is at fault.

In Line 2 it says `Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Eva/.ssh/id_rsa):`.
That full filename in the parantheses is the default, obviously Windows cannot access a file like that. If you type the Windows equivalent (`c:\Users\Eva\.ssh\id_rsa`), it should work.

Before running this, you also need to create the folder. You can do this by running `mkdir c:\Users\Eva\.ssh`, or by created the folder ".ssh." from File Explorer (note the second dot at the end, which will get removed automatically, and is required to create a folder that has a dot at the beginning).

```
c:\Users\Administrator\.ssh>ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myemail.com"
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa): C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
... myemail@myemail.com
The key's randomart image is:...`
```

I know this is an old thread, but I thought the answer might help others.

Comment: Note that you must create the directory before running the command. To Create a windows directory starting with a . you have to put a . before it and it will automatically be removed ".ssh." creates ".ssh".

Comment: That IS the answer. I've been suffering from the same problem and that i.e. entering the pathname the Windows way, solved the problem instantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you are executing that command from a DOS session (see [this thread](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/12689)), and that means you need to create the `.ssh` directory before said command.

Or you can execute it from the bash session (part of the msysgit distribution), and it should work.

Comment: In my case this was the correct answer, just forgot to create the directories specified in path

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue. I had to provide the full path using Windows conventions.
At this step:

`Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Eva/.ssh/id_rsa):`

Provide the following value:

`c:\users\eva\.ssh\id_rsa`

Comment: OSX too: instead of ~/.ssh/id_rsa I had to use /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Yep, on macOS I needed to type in the whole path of the intended keyfile for the *second* SSH key I generated (the first one worked with just the file name).

Comment: I had to provide the full path too on High Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create the .ssh folder yourself for saving ssh keys.

By the way, I used this path style: `C:/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same problem for a while just now (using Mac). Here is what I did and it finally worked:
(1) Confirm the .ssh directory exists:

```
#show all files including hidden
ls -a
```

(2) Accept all default values by *just* pressing enter at the prompt

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again:
```

You should get a message :

```
Your identification has been saved in /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
BZA156:HVhsjsdhfdkjfdfhdX+BundfOytLezXvbx831/s youremail.@email.com
The key's randomart image is:XXXXX
```

PS If you are configuring git for rails, do the following ([source](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan)):

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global user.name "yourusername"
git config --global user.email "youremail@email.com"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremail@email.com"
```

(then accept all defaults by pressing enter)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows I had to create the environment variable `HOME` pointing to my user profile first `(C:\Users\<name>)` or whatever directory you prefer.

Then start a new command line window, create a a `.ssh` directory in your user profile or choosen diretory using `mkdir ".ssh"` command.

After doing that I was able to use the ssh-keygen without any path problems.

Answer (score 1):

I was using bash on windows that came with git. The problem was I assumed the tilde (~) which I was using to denote my home path would expand properly. It does work when using cd, but to fix this error I had to just give it the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should work fine on a Mac, but on Windows, two additional steps are necessary.

1. Create a new folder in the desired location and name it ".ssh." (note the closing dot - this will vanish, but is required to create a folder beginning with ".")
2. When prompted, use the file path format C:/Users/NAME/.ssh/id_rsa (note no closing dot on .ssh).

Saving the id_rsa key in this location should solve the permission error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. 
Solution on windows:

1. open start menu and type cmd
2. Right and choose run as administrator
3. Then type   cd Users_YOURUSERNAME_\
   Replace "*YOURUSERNAME*" with your windows account name
4. The type: `mkdir .ssh`

This will create a .ssh folder.

Answer (score 1):

**For MacOS**

Open terminal 
and make sure you have .ssh directory.

On your home(~) folder enter `ls -hal` and you will see all hidden directories and make sure you have .ssh directory, if not do `mkdir .ssh`

then enter this `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@myemail.com"`

then you have: `Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa):`

press Enter (you don't need to enter nothing if you agree with that path or you need to enter your path from root of volume)

then follow answer what is gonna ask press Enter.

Check it here https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: its not working Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):

Answer (score 1):

For windows use enter button 3 times

Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Rupesh/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:

its work for me...

Answer (score 1):

on Mac, you first have to`cd ~/.ssh` then you can do `ssh-keygen`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1 using CMDER, I created the ssh key with this file path /c/Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa_whatever, the problem was the : that I was using. With this path I didn't create the folder before running the command, there is no need to run mkdir because the command will create the folder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**For Linux**
on terminal use:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "<comment>"
```

this generate new modeled key. Or can create as:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "any comment"
```

Then continue following terminal.. give any name to the file as asked
Again follow it with empty passphrase..and continue

Then goto the /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 or /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (is hidden file..look by doing ctrl+h to unhide hidden file) and copy it to gitlab => profile => setting => ssh => create new key there by pasting copied key and NOTE: public key always starts with ssh.
Enjoy!
Help:[gitlab-Help](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#common-steps-for-generating-an-ssh-key-pair)

Answer (score 0):

In my case just went to the `.ssh` directory with git-bash -

```
Users\User\.ssh
```

and then tried `ssh-keygen` command to generate the key and Voila, it worked!