# Git: Permission denied (publickey) fatal - Could not read from remote repository. while cloning Git repository

Tags: git, git-clone

I am unable to clone a Git repository, and getting this error:

```
krishna.soni@KRISHNACHANDRAS /c/Projects $ git clone http://stage.abc.com:10088/pqr
http://<url>/<repository> Cloning into '<repository>'... fatal: could not read Username for 'http://<url>': No such file or directory
```

I've read [Bitbucket, Windows and “fatal: could not read Password for”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923193/bitbucket-windows-and-fatal-could-not-read-password-for), but still have the problem.

I proceeded further but am now getting this error

```
sh.exe": chown: command not found

krishna.soni@KRISHNACHANDRAS /c
$ git clone ssh://krishna.sonipayu.in@stage.payupaisa.
/projects
Cloning into 'C:/projects'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

> krishna.soni@KRISHNACHANDRAS /c
>     $ git clone ssh:<url>
>     ts
>     Cloning into 'C:/projects'...
>     Permission denied (publickey).
>     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you sure it's a git repository?

Comment: yes , it is . I am new to git, getting this error while cloning . I added email and name in global config file using commands           git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

Comment: The main reason is that the repo can't recognize you as a user the git-server. Could you access the server via ssh?

Comment: If someone is having this issue while using Github, follow the steps mentioned here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent It worked for me.

Comment: The issue is with the ssh key, As you are using ssh, its needs a ssh key which matches with the git repo. To do so, follow the below commands :  1. ssh-keygen, press enter till the ssh key generates. 2. Copy the ssh key from the location "Your public key has been saved in <Loc>" cat <Loc>. 3. Now in github, goto profile -->setting -->ssh and gpg key and add new ssh key and save. 4. Now clone again

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It looks like a permissions issue - not a Windows 7 issue.

Your ssh key is not authorised - `Permission denied (publickey)`.

You need to create a public ssh key and ask the administrator of the Git repository to add the `ssh` public key

Information on how to do this: [Saving ssh key fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430311/saving-ssh-key-fails/8600087#8600087)

Comment: This is weird. The repository is public and I am cloning the public repository. I am not sure why I should ask the administrator for permission to clone his/her public repository hosted on Github.

Comment: Yeah, is false, you don't need to ask the administrator anything, is a problem with the local git.

Comment: Why is it difficult? I succeeded but it was not painless.

Comment: You don't need to authorize a key for public repos, just use HTTPS protocol: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33072867/1385678

Comment: Thanks @First Zero I have struggled with this problem. Firstly I have set up SSH-Agent, then have added Keys to SSH Agent (you can use this link `https://www.toolsqa.com/git/clone-repository-using-ssh/` and then I have copyed key from generated file and create SSH-Key in settings my profile in Bitbucket

Answer (score 302):

For people that come here that are just trying to get the repository but don't care about the protocol (ssh / https), you might just want to **use https instead of ssh** (if it's supported).

So for example you use

```
git clone https://github.com/%REPOSITORYFOLDER%/%REPOSITORYNAME%.git
```

instead of

```
git clone git@github.com:%REPOSITORYFOLDER%/%REPOSITORYNAME%.git
```

Note that GitHub **deprecated** password authentication (https login) **for private repositories** due to it not keeping up with the latest security standards, use a [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Note also that since March 1, 2022, Bitbucket users are no longer able to use their Atlassian account password with git over https as well, but instead need to use Bitbucket [app passwords](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/).

Comment: This is the most appropriate fallback plan if ssh permissions don't get resolved or you want to skip that part.

Comment: This answer changed the mechanism from `ssh` to `https`. It is not solving the original problem by using ssh to access the repository. I wonder how this can keep getting upvoted as a good answer to the question. The other answers down below are solving it properly.

Comment: The original problem is a git newbie trying to clone a repo. If the goal is to pull down a public repo, this is the quickest effective answer.

Comment: Https is no longer supported when cloning private repositories - only ssh or a PAT are supported. This answer should clarify that https is only reliable for public repos.

Comment: 1. Create App Password - Give all permissions
2. Change the remote url to https counterpart
3. Pull/Push/Commit - when asked for password give the password obtained in 2

Comment: If you are facing issue for bitbucket then here is the link for the same .
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Answer (score 158):

If there is still issue around access after creating SSH and adding it in your Bitbucket account or wherever, you need to do the following in terminal on GitBash, OSX or Linux:

```
# Lists already added identities (‘ssh keys’)
ssh-add -l
```

Then, if you don't see your key listed, add it with the following (replace `identity` with its real name):

```
# Add a new identity
ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity
```

This worked for me.

Comment: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity` return error `/Users/lee/.ssh/identity: No such file or directory`

Comment: Running "ssh-add" from "~/.ssh" (and entering the passphrase for my "~/.ssh/id_rsa" file when prompted) solved the problem for me.

Comment: I was able to pull my repo but not push without doing this, cheers!

Comment: @james Furey answer helped me the sourcetree to identify the ssh url as a git repo.

Comment: I would much rather use ssh (this solution), over https (another upvoted answer). This answer helped me solve the same ssh permission issue.

Comment: `ssh-add -l` gives `The agent has no identities.`

Comment: `/home/osboxes/.ssh/identity: No such file or directory
`

Comment: This gives me the error `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

Comment: To load the SSH agent with your private key `eval $(ssh-agent) ssh-add ~/.ssh/<private_key>`

Comment: worked for me... after hours of sweating and trying different things. Only thing is instead of identity in the end use the name in your own system. Go to .ssh folder by doing cd command in terminal and then type 'ls' command in terminal. And then replay the "identity" from above command with your own file.

Go to sourcetree terminal and:
`cd ~` then 
`cd .ssh` then 
`ls` then 
(copy the name without .pub extension) then 
(run this command) `ssh-add ~/.ssh/(copied name)`

Comment: This worked for me, BUT - I had to go my users root folder, find the .SSH folder (hidden), have a look in there for the name of the ssh key that I was missing, and use that in place of the one recommended above.  Then had to enter the passcode for the key, and that was it, all sorted.

Comment: if you get this error while adding the identities: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." try to start the ssh-agent first: `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/

Comment: I would like to add what I found after I did ssh-add. If you see "Permissions 0777 for '/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open." Fix this problem by running "chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa" and then run "ssh-add" again.

Comment: @lee When creating the files for ssh key, you might not have used default location. You will need to copy the private key file to .ssh folder.

Answer (score 46):

I faced the same problem with **GitHub**. Here's how to solve it!

1. Generate a SSH key on your computer as described here : [Generating SSH keys](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).
2. Login your GitHub account: [GitHub Login](https://github.com/login).
3. In your account, add the newly generated SSH Key: [My account SSH keys](https://github.com/settings/ssh).
4. Try again to `git clone` the project.

Comment: Worked like charm!!

Comment: I've now used this answer on 3 new operating systems in the last 5 years and it's worked perfectly every time.

Comment: Apparently High Sierra requires user to register the key in .ssh/config file. El Capitan somehow managed without it.

Comment: This doesn't give a solution to the question, it just links to the documentation. After step 3, `ssh -T git@github.com` works fine, but `git clone` fails.

Comment: Yay, I've solved my problem. Since I was using my own ssh config, I had to do `git clone myconfig:user/repo.git`. Silly mistake on my part.

Comment: What if this repo is being used in some other location. It may stop working as the key has changed. Is it possible to match github repo ssh key with that of the local machine instead.?

Comment: In case someone found this answer doesn't work, you might need to restart your machine. This helps me solve my problem

Answer (score 23):

I've had this issue on a Mac - while I setup SSH correctly to access my Git repository, after restart (and some time the Mac was on a standoff), all my credentials were removed. Apparently, for some reason the pub key was set to 644 which caused it to be removed from the keychain. To readd:

- `chmod 600` the public key
- `ssh-add ~/.ssh/[your private key]` - this should display that identity has been added. The key file you want is the one without the .pub extension.
- `ssh-add -l` should show you newly added identity

edit: apparently MacOS has tendency of removing keys - after downloading the High Sierra update (but I've not installed it yet) my key has been removed and I've had to add it again via `ssh-add`

Comment: This solution is still accurate after you upgrade macOS High Sierra to Version 10.13.1. Specifically, Sourcetree was the app that surfaced the issue when I tried to push a commit up to a remote repository. The above steps fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had this issue on 10.13.4 and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

For me, when i wanted to **clone** from my repository, i had the same message noticed before "Permission denied (publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository". The solution for my case is **to not use sudo before clone**  That's it.

Comment: Well yeah that makes sense because when you `sudo` you are doing things as root. It's unlikely that root has access to your repository.

Answer (score 13):

I also faced the same issue. I did the following and it worked for me:

1. Generate Keys from the GIT GUI client on Windows. Copy this key to the clipboard.
2. Open up your account on `bitBucket/` git website, and add this key to your profile. This way, the server knows that you are a legitimate user accessing from a legitimate system.
3. That's it. All push commands worked for me henceforth.

Comment: This helped me see that I had generated my RSA without running Git Bash as Administrator which placed my RSA key in the "h" drive :oops:

Comment: Definitely the best option in Windows.

Answer (score 10):

I had the similar issue.  I change the ssh keys and restarted and tried all other 'n' solutions. But the actual issue for me was our gitlab default protocol changed from ssh to https.

check the remote url with

```
git remote -v
```

change the remote url

```
git remote set-url origin https://URL
```

Comment: It's perfect, We don't need to configure ssh.

Comment: I had to do the same. The ssh key was not working for me in this case

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org:xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxt/': Port number ended with 'r'

Comment: I had similar issue. My ssh key is properly configured but only difference I observed is with cloned repo the different protocol. set it with ```https``` worked for me.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for me. Swapping the remote origin from git@ to https://.

Answer (score 8):

Github(or Bitbucket) can't find your ssh key in their server.

Just add your key in your account setting.

Answer (score 7):

If you generate new public ssh key and inserted it to bitbucket or github and

it not helped - **please try to restart your PC**. It helped me!!

Comment: I had to close the terminal and open a new one to see it working.

Answer (score 7):

For Fedora 33+ and Bitbucket users:

The issue happens because the hash algorithm is outdated. As mentioned on [Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html) there are two options:

### Option 1:

Add to the `~/.ssh/config` file. (If the file doesn't exist, just create it.)

```
Host bitbucket.org
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

### Option 2:

Using a more secure algorithm.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Comment: The accepted key types line worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a new ssh key by running `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

Answer (score 6):

## In macOS / Linux (Ubuntu):

**1.** To Authenticate you need to add your public part of your SSH key pair to bitbucket from within your user settings: User Settings --> SSH keys

You will find the said public part in your ~/.ssh directory, usually `id_rsa.pub` . note the  `.pub` part of the file name for Public.
it will help you to generate one if you don't already have one

> You are not done yet ...

**2.** You need to let your system know what key to use with which remote host, so add these lines to your ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME
```

Where `PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME` is the name of private part of your SSH key pair, if you haven't messed with it, usually its default name is : `id_rsa`
in this case replace `PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME` above with `id_rsa`(the private key  DOES NOT have a  `.pub` extension)

Comment: Note, you misspelled "Ubuntu" -- edits must be at least 6 chars so I can't suggest the edit :)

Answer (score 5):

I got the error...

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

...when I was trying to make contact from a Git Bash prompt to Bitbucket after my laptop died from a bad Windows 10 update and was returned to factory settings.  I had restored all my ssh files from a backup.

The cause of the error turned out to be a mismatch in my Windows account name after the computer rebuild.  I learned that the public key file `id_rsa.pub` ends with an easily readable string comprising my Windows account name followed by an `@` sign and then the computer name.

When I originally set up my computer, I created my Windows account name including my middle initial but when my computer was reset to factory settings, our new DevOps guy created my account name without my middle initial.

To resolve the issue, I simply edited my public key file `id_rsa.pub` and removed the middle initial in my name at the end.  I had stuck with the same computer name so that was okay.  I copied the file contents to the Windows clipboard. I then signed into Bitbucket, went to Bitbucket Settings under my avatar, and added a new public key where I pasted in the new contents.

Back at the Git Bash prompt, I confirmed that it now worked by entering the command...

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

...and I got back a message that I was signed in.

Answer (score 5):

Useful thread and I don't bring much new to the table. The step I took is also part of the description Maxime helpfully points to but some may overlook it. The section is [Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

I had already generated my ssh-key but after a reboot I was unable to clone one of my own repositories.

I had to start the ssh-agent and add the private key to this agent in order to clone.

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: This method worked for me. I think the ssh authentication agent had not picked up the recently generated keys, and running these commands solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

After changing permissions of folder in which I was cloning, it worked:

`sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /var/projects`

Comment: This did the trick, weird enough that `sudo` does not enable you to do that :/

Comment: What exactly does this do? Who is ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue while running `git clone` command from windows command line. But the command runs successfully from **Git Bash**.

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding your ssh key to your private keychain. It worked for me

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[your-private-key]
```

Comment: "unknown option -- K"

Comment: Out of all answers given this is the only answer that solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If all fails, as was the case with me, Uninstall GIT, reinstall. For some reason this fixes.

P.S.

1. I tried generating new Keys and Updating at SSH public keys
2. Also tried deleting all keys and tried to create a fresh key.
3. And NO, nothing wrong with my .gitconfig

Answer (score 2):

fix for `hub` cli tool:

- `git config --global hub.protocol https` for long term
- `git remote add OOPS https://github.com/isomorphisms/go.git` && `git push OOPS` for immediate fix

---

This error occurs with the `hub` command line tool because of their wrong default `hub.protocol` git-config value. They set repos to

```
git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
```

instead of what github actually accepts, namely `https://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git`.

---

Reading `LESS=+/"HTTPS instead" man hub` will explain where the above "long-term fix" command comes from.

Answer (score 1):

While cloning, I had a similar issue [ my ERROR: 
   Permission denied (publickey).
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
   Please make sure you have the correct access rights  .. etc
]

-- I was using bitBucket/UBUNTU14.04 in my case, but **ALREADY** had a set of key files that I had previously generated AND I had changed the name of the files. I simply **COPIED** the files to the standard id_rsa & id_rsa.pub name format. I then re-ran the command with out issue.

**OBTW**: *I could have also used the password prompt by using the HTTP style clone.*

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to clone open source projects to submit a Pull Request:

I wanted to clone an open source project so I could submit some pull requests. The problem was that I didn't have permissions from the owner of the project. No matter, since my intention was to submit a PR, here is a viable alternative:

My solution:

1. Fork Repository

[image: Fork Repo]

2. Then clone from your forked repository.
   [image: Clone from forked Repo]
3. Work on your features and then submit a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Remove remote origin

**git remote remove origin**

Add HTTP remote origin

Comment: It's helped a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "user@account.com"`
2. `sudo cat /var/root/.ssh/{generated}.pub | pbcopy`
3. Add it to SSH keys
4. Be sure your remote URL is https not ssh.

Comment: wow <3 after 2 hours ! 
the last comment saved me! thankkkkkksss!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on linux.  I solved the problem by logging into the github server and creating a deploy key.  That's under settings for the repository.  Then, I copied and pasted my public key (which is usually in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, but your configuration might be different). There is a check box to give this key write access.  Click on it (unless you are using git to deploy only, in which case, don't click on it).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  My solution was to logout and login again as my ssh-agent had become out of sync with the remote ssh key.

Adding this here just in case anyone has seen that the other answers don't seem to apply to their situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while setting up ssh for gitlab. I already have ssh for `github` and i could not overwrite that.
The steps that worked for me are :

1. Generate SSH with new path and add it to ssh list `ssh-add /path/to/new/id_rsa`.
2. Create a file named `config` in `~/.ssh/` using. I used `vi ~/.ssh/config/`.
3. Add this to the newly created file

`# GitLab.com server
Host gitlab.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /path/to/new/id_rsa`

4. Save and quit.

After that restart the terminal and try pushing, it should work

Answer (score 0):

solution:
On the server you are trying to clone to or push from
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Go to GitHub, settings, **SSH and GPG Keys** , **New SSH key**
paste key.

Answer (score 0):

I see this errormessage has a lot of different reasons.
I had the same error when trying to set up locally another repository alongside one already fully working with ssh etc. and connect it to same server, but other repository. No answers were here to be found, but I figured it out. So I post it. Hopefully helps someone.

```
git remote add origin git@git.ourserver.com:teamalpha/repositorytwo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

if  none of these answers help and

1. you are using Windows
2. you generate your key with Putty or you have installed Putty on
   your PC
3. you generate your key with CMD or PowerShell

Try

1. delete your keys
2. search on windows for Git Bash, then generate a
   new key with Git Bash command line
3. add public key to your online Repo

Then, you will find after git clone and type yes to confirm, it should begin to clone

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps detailed in [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent) and

[Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent).

In my case `~/.profile` file was not present in my Windows.
I had to create it, then added the script provided in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, suddenly it clicked to my mind what could go wrong.

- Generate a SSH key on your computer as described here : [Generating
  SSH keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).

**Here is what I was doing wrong**

While generating the **ssh key** was using the below command, but I wasn't using **sudo** and while cloning I was using "**sudo** git clone ssh_repo_url", because while cloning I need folder to be created which my user doesn't have the permission

**My Wrong way to generate ssh**

$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"

**The correct way, if while cloning using** **sudo**

$ **sudo** ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"

- Login your GitHub account: GitHub Login.
- In your account, add the newly generated SSH Key: My account SSH
  keys.
- Try again to git clone the project. (with **sudo** if key generated with **sudo**)

Answer (score 0):

After logging into bitbucket through the browser,
my push to origin starting working.

Answer (score -2):

It may be stupid but it happened to us:

If you are using bitbucket and Sourcetree and you just copy paste the clone URL to the new repo dialog it will show the same error when pulling or pushing.

Make sure you delete the 'git clone' stuff before the URL.