# git push is not work when I first push

Tags: git

git first push is not work,whitch point out the error is:

```
"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

What should I do?

Comment: Well.."*make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists*".

Comment: What have you tried to verify that "you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists" ?

Comment: add your ssh key to settings(github or bitbucket vs) settings.

Comment: I have to add SSH to git, but, through my search related issues on the Internet that I may be SSH, but what is the specific problem, I will not find..

Comment: did you generate ssh keys and add the settings? If your ssh keys is not authorized you are not allow to pull & push to repo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255438/permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-whil

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help.

Your ssh key is not authorised :- `Permission denied (publickey)`.

How to do this click here:-

[Permission denied (publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository. while cloning Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255438/permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-whil)