# Git Clone Repo to Ubuntu Server Key Error

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh-keys

I am trying to clone my remote github repo to my EC2 Ubuntu server. When I run `sudo git clone git@github.com:user/test.git`

I have the message

```
Cloning into 'test'...

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What do I need to setup to get my github repo in my server? Are there keys I need to add to my Github account? My server?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub isn't able to authenticate you.Your SSH key is not authorised. I would suggest you to get a look at the following links because this subject has already been treated:

[Link 1 Subject: GitHub Error Message - Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey)
[Link 2 Subject: Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255438/permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-whil)

Hope this helped !