# ssh ec2 via git: permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2

So I was able to ssh to my server via git, but now if I do:

```
git remote add deploy ssh://ubuntu@54.165.145.227/home/ubuntu/repo
```

(no error message)

```
git push deploy +master:refs/heads/master
```

After this command, I get this message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So presently, I can't push my files to the server. I'm a newbie in ssh and git, so please fully detail your answer. If you need more information, I can do it, but again, be clear :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connecting to the correct domain (sometimes DNS can be pesky), try

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

You should get an output with a couple of things but check for

*"192.30.252.0/22"*

Check to make sure your key is valid or not already in use. 
If you're connecting through port 443 (HTTPS over SSH) try switching to port 22 or 80

Comment: I've tried your command, but it gives me "192.30.252.130 port 22" rather.

How can I make sure my key is valid and not already in use?

Comment: When I press yes after it asks me, I get:

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/boubou/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/boubou/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/boubou/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/boubou/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: "To verify that you have a private key generated and loaded into SSH, type ssh-add -l" https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey (might be helpful.) I guess the next thing after that is to make sure the key is attached to your account.

Comment: I have no .ssh directory on my local computer, should I make one? And if so, how?

Comment: Hm, this could be tricky, and that is for another question you might have to ask. I assume you're on a linux machine, and that you're using keys generated by you or git, so I'd say, make sure your Key is attached to your account and verify that your key is valid. Beyond that I'm not sure, sorry. Perhaps this related topic will help with the 'key issue' (as I'm calling it) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430311/saving-ssh-key-fails/8600087#8600087